# Read XML String using StAX

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax

I am using stax for the first time to parse an XML String. I have found some examples but can't get my code to work.  This is the latest version of my code:

```
public class AddressResponseParser
{
    private static final String STATUS = "status";
    private static final String ADDRESS_ID = "address_id";
    private static final String CIVIC_ADDRESS = "civic_address";

    String status = null;
    String addressId = null;
    String civicAddress = null;

    public static AddressResponse parseAddressResponse(String response)
    {

        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = response.getBytes("UTF-8");
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
            XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);

            while (reader.hasNext())
            {
                int event = reader.next();

                if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT)
                {
                    String element = reader.getLocalName();

                    if (element.equals(STATUS))
                    {
                        status = reader.getElementText();
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (element.equals(ADDRESS_ID))
                    {
                        addressId = reader.getText();
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (element.equals(CIVIC_ADDRESS))
                    {
                        civicAddress = reader.getText();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Couldn't parse AddressResponse", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've put watches on "event" and "reader.getElementText()".  When the code is stopped on

```
String element = reader.getLocalName();
```

the "reader.getElementText()" value is displayed, but as soon as it moves away from that line it can't be evaluated.  When the code is stopped on:

```
status = reader.getElementText();
```

the "element" watch displays the correct value.  Finally, when I step the code one more line, I catch this exception:

```
(com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException) com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Current state not START_ELEMENT
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,29]
```

I've tried using `status = reader.getText();` instead, but then I get this exception:

```
(java.lang.IllegalStateException) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a textual event (END_ELEMENT)
```

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong??

EDIT:

Adding JUnit code used to test:

```
public class AddressResponseParserTest
{
    private String status = "OK";
    private String address_id = "123456";
    private String civic_address = "727";

    @Test
    public void testAddressResponseParser() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, XMLStreamException
    {
        AddressResponse parsedResponse = AddressResponseParser.parseAddressResponse(this.responseXML());

        assertEquals(this.status, parsedResponse.getStatus());

        assertEquals(this.address_id, parsedResponse.getAddress()
                .getAddressId());
        assertEquals(this.civic_address, parsedResponse.getAddress()
                .getCivicAddress());
    }

    private String responseXML()
    {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        buffer.append("<response>");
        buffer.append("<status>OK</status>");
        buffer.append("<address>");
        buffer.append("<address_id>123456</address_id>");
        buffer.append("<civic_address>727</civic_address>");
        buffer.append("</address>");
        buffer.append("</response>");

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your XML data look like? Are you sure it is well-formed? (Perhaps show us a small amount)

Comment: The XML is a String response from another class/method that my code will be calling.  I'm writing a JUnit to test the parser.  I've added the JUnit code to the question, including the method that generates the XML for the test.

Comment: my personal approach would be to find a stAX tutorial and make sure it works for me, then extend it to cover your requirements. I note that you only trap START_ELEMENT - I would add an `} else {` clause that logs the other events. That will tell you how far you have got through the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution that uses XMLEventReader instead of XMLStreamReader:

```
public MyObject parseXML(String xml)
    throws XMLStreamException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] byteArray = xml.getBytes("UTF-8");
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);

    MyObject object = new MyObject();

    while (reader.hasNext())
    {
        XMLEvent event = (XMLEvent) reader.next();

        if (event.isStartElement())
        {
            StartElement element = event.asStartElement();

            if (element.getName().getLocalPart().equals("ElementOne"))
            {
                event = (XMLEvent) reader.next();

                if (event.isCharacters())
                {
                     String elementOne = event.asCharacters().getData();
                     object.setElementOne(elementOne);
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (element.getName().getLocalPart().equals("ElementTwo"))
            {
                event = (XMLEvent) reader.next();
                if (event.isCharacters())
                {
                     String elementTwo = event.asCharacters().getData();
                     object.setElementTwo(elementTwo);
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

I would still be interested in seeing a solution using XMLStreamReader.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you read javadocs for Stax: since it is fully streaming parsing mode, only information contained by the current event is available. There are some exceptions, however; getElementText() for example must start at START_ELEMENT, but will then try to combine all textual tokens from inside current element; and when returning, it will point to matching END_ELEMENT.

Conversely, getText() on START_ELEMENT will not returning anything useful (since START_ELEMENT refers to tag, not child text tokens/nodes 'inside' start/end element pair). If you want to use it instead, you have to explicitly move cursor in stream by calling streamReader.next(); whereas getElementText() does it for you.

So what is causing the error? After you have consumed all start/end-element pairs, next token will be END_ELEMENT (matching whatever was the parent tag). So you must check for the case where you get END_ELEMENT, instead of yet another START_ELEMENT.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue as I was getting "IllegalStateException: Not a textual event" message
When I looked through your code I figured out that if you had a condition:

```
if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
....
addressId = reader.getText(); // it throws exception here
....
}
```

(Please note: StaXMan did point out this in his answer!)

This happens since to fetch text, XMLStreamReader instance must have encountered 'XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS' event!

There maybe a better way to do this...but this is a quick and dirty fix (*I have only shown lines of code that may be of interest*)
Now to make this happen modify your code slightly:

```
// this will tell the XMLStreamReader that it is appropriate to read the text
boolean pickupText = false

while(reader.hasNext()){

if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
   if( (reader.getLocalName().equals(STATUS) )
   || ( (reader.getLocalName().equals(STATUS) )
   || ((reader.getLocalName().equals(STATUS) ))
         // indicate the reader that it has to pick text soon!
     pickupText = true;
   }
}else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS){
  String textFromXML = reader.getText();
  // process textFromXML ...

  //...

  //set pickUpText false
  pickupText = false;

 }    

}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with XMLStreamReader:

```
   XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
   Map<String, String> elements = new HashMap<>();

try {
   XMLStreamReader xmlReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(file);
   String elementValue = "";
   
   while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
      int xmlEventType = xmlReader.next();
      
      switch (xmlEventType) {  
          // Check for Start Elements
          case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
              
              //Get current Element Name
              String elementName = xmlReader.getLocalName();
              
              if(elementName.equals("td")) {
              //Get Elements Value
              elementValue = xmlReader.getElementText();
              }
              
              //Add the new Start Element to the Map
              elements.put(elementName, elementValue);                
              break;
          default:
             break;
          }    
   }
   //Close Session
   xmlReader.close();        
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: The question was to parse XML from a string not a file. Examples like yours abound out there.