# Error while running Wildfly 10.1.0 - Failed to parse configuration and Current event not START_ELEMENT

Tags: java, docker, jboss, wildfly-10, keycloak

Whenever I try try to run my docker container which contains Wildfly Server 10.1.0 I get the following error:

## JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -Djboss.server.log.dir=/ext/logs

```
JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly

JAVA: /opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java

JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Djboss.server.log.dir=/ext/logs
```

=========================================================================

```
14:16:45,038 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
14:16:45,634 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
14:16:45,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
14:16:46,899 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131) [wildfly-controller-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:357) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299) [wildfly-controller-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current event not START_ELEMENT
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getAttributeValue(BasicStreamReader.java:625) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.getAttributeValue(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:240) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.invalidAttributeValue(ParseUtils.java:150) [wildfly-controller-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:119) [wildfly-controller-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml$DefaultExtensionHandler.parseExtensions(StandaloneXml.java:126) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:218) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49) [wildfly-server-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123) [wildfly-controller-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
... 3 more

14:16:47,059 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
14:16:47,313 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) stopped in 113ms
```

What mistake am I doing in my standalone.xml file ?

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.0">
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
    <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-subsystem"/>
</extensions>
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local allowed-users="*" default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
    <server-identities>
      <ssl>
        <keystore alias="___" key-password="password" keystore-password="____" path="____.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
      </ssl>
    </server-identities>
  </security-realm>
</security-realms>
    <audit-log>
        <formatters>
            <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
        </formatters>
        <handlers>
            <file-handler formatter="json-formatter" name="file" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </handlers>
        <logger enabled="false" log-boot="true" log-read-only="false">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="file"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
    </audit-log>
    <management-interfaces>
        <http-interface http-upgrade-enabled="true" security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
    <access-control provider="simple">
        <role-mapping>
            <role name="SuperUser">
                <include>
                    <user name="$local"/>
                </include>
            </role>
        </role-mapping>
    </access-control>
</management>
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler autoflush="true" name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file path="______"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:1.0">
        <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
        <default-thread-pool name="batch"/>
        <job-repository name="in-memory">
            <in-memory/>
        </job-repository>
        <thread-pool name="batch">
            <max-threads count="10"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver module="com.h2database.h2" name="h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}" scan-interval="5000"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
        <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <concurrent>
            <context-services>
                <context-service jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" name="default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
            </context-services>
            <managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-thread-factory context-service="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" name="default"/>
            </managed-thread-factories>
            <managed-executor-services>
                <managed-executor-service context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" keepalive-time="5000" name="default"/>
            </managed-executor-services>
            <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-service context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" keepalive-time="3000" name="default"/>
            </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
        </concurrent>
        <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful cache-ref="simple" default-access-timeout="5000" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <pools>
            <bean-instance-pools>
                <!-- Automatically configure pools. Alternatively, max-pool-size can be set to a specific value -->
                <strict-max-pool derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                <strict-max-pool derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </bean-instance-pools>
        </pools>
        <caches>
            <cache name="simple"/>
            <cache aliases="passivating clustered" name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan"/>
        </caches>
        <passivation-stores>
            <passivation-store cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000" name="infinispan"/>
        </passivation-stores>
        <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <timer-service default-data-store="default-file-store" thread-pool-name="default">
            <data-stores>
                <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </data-stores>
        </timer-service>
        <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <thread-pools>
            <thread-pool name="default">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </thread-pools>
        <default-security-domain value="other"/>
        <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        <log-system-exceptions value="true"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
        <worker name="default"/>
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
        <cache-container default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server" name="server">
            <local-cache name="default">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan" name="web">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" name="ejb">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan" name="hibernate">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction max-entries="10000" strategy="LRU"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <eviction max-entries="10000" strategy="LRU"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:4.0">
        <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
        <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
        <default-workmanager>
            <short-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </short-running-threads>
            <long-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </long-running-threads>
        </default-workmanager>
        <cached-connection-manager/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
        <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
        <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default" name="default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">
        <endpoint/>
        <http-connector connector-ref="default" name="http-remoting-connector" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:request-controller:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
        <deployment-permissions>
            <maximum-set>
                <permission class="java.security.AllPermission"/>
            </maximum-set>
        </deployment-permissions>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain cache-type="default" name="other">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain cache-type="default" name="jboss-web-policy">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain cache-type="default" name="jboss-ejb-policy">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain cache-type="default" name="jaspitest">
                <authentication-jaspi>
                    <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                        <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/>
                    </login-module-stack>
                    <auth-module code="Dummy"/>
                </authentication-jaspi>
            </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="keycloak">
      <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule" flag="required"/>
      </authentication>
    </security-domain>
  </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:3.0">
        <core-environment>
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" redirect-socket="https" socket-binding="http"/>
            <host alias="________" name="default-host">
                <location handler="welcome-content" name="/"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        <https-listener name="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" socket-binding="https"/>
  </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10" name="server-header"/>
            <response-header header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1" name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler" name="RecordingHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:3.0"/>
<n2:subsystem xmlns:n2="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
  <secure-deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1" name="____.war">
    <realm>_____</realm>
    <realm-public-key>______</realm-public-key>
    <auth-server-url>_____</auth-server-url>
    <ssl-required>______</ssl-required>
    <resource>________</resource>
    <public-client>______</public-client>
    <connection-pool-size>____</connection-pool-size>
    <disable-trust-manager>______</disable-trust-manager>
    <allow-any-hostname>_____</allow-any-hostname>
    <truststore>________</truststore>
    <truststore-password>________</truststore-password>
  <credential name="secret">_______</credential>
  </secure-deployment>
</n2:subsystem>
</profile>
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">

    <any-address/>
</interface>
    <interface name="public">

    <any-address/>
</interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group default-interface="public" name="standard-sockets" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding interface="management" name="management-http" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding interface="management" name="management-https" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

Comment: Is this your complete xml configuration? I don't see the main </server> tag, which could be involved in a bad parse.

Comment: Assuming </server> was just a mistake, I've been playing with this myself. I can't duplicate your stack trace using your standalone.xml. Instead I get complaints about 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
         at org.jboss.dmr.StringModelValue.asBoolean(StringModelValue.java:154)

which indicates that it doesn't like your ______ values in the keycloak subsystem xml.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6194206/6768037) will help you debug the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current event not START_ELEMENT - it does sound like unbalanced tags somehow.

Comment: @JonSampson : i purposely place '_____' as it was confidential data.

Comment: @JonSampson : I have checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652299/read-xml-string-using-stax/6194206#6194206 link but really don't understand what I have misplaced in my xml :(

Comment: Make a backup copy of your standalone.xml then delete all the tags under <secure-deployment>. See if the server starts up. If it does (or gives you an error about missing arguments), then begin adding tags back 1 by 1 until you arrive at the problem. My wild guess is that there's a problem in the confidential data.

Comment: @JonSampson I'll surely try this and if success I'll let u know. By the way one instance is already running with same standalon.xml and hence I was worried wat could be wrong......but I'll try your method n hope I'll be closer to solution

Comment: That's an interesting note. Could be an environmental difference then somehow. Good luck. I hope you get it!

Comment: Maybe that is because that instance is running on Wildfly 10.0.0 and I am trying on Wildfly 10.1.0....not sure but maybe I guess